# How to build a Table adding one or more values different from those defined by Table options?

Tags: list-manipulation

Imagine I wanted to add a value 0.3 to the `Table`. How would you do?

```
  vectorj = {0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1};
  Table[i, {i, 0, Length[vectorj]}]
```

I tried with:

```
 List[0.3, Flatten[Table[i, {i, 10}]]]
```

but couldn't unnest the last stage.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean - at all. You are not the first person who use the word `Table` in a uncomprehensible way. It seems that you are not aware that `Table` is a instruction to construct some Lists . The underlying fondamental object is `List`. `Table` is not the only instruction to construct `List`. There are many others (`Range`,`Array`....)

Comment: I'm curious to know from what langage comes your vocabulary, habits etc...

Comment: ...especially since `Flatten[]` is a no-op in your example.

Comment: @IgorRivin what is a no-op?

Comment: @andre then I apologize, consider I meant build a `List` through the instruction `Table`. If I mistaked is just because I am new to Mathematica

Comment: OK, but even with this new information, we can't guess what you want to do. Maybe simply `{0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1}+0.3` which gives ` {0.3, 0.31, 0.32, 0.35, 0.4, 0.5, 0.8, 1.3}` ?

Comment: @andre I think that was clear from the example `List[0.3,etc]`. I would like to build a `List`where a value is given by me and the rest is called from a previous Table: {0.3,1,2,3,4,5,...}

Comment: OK you by "add" you mean prepend (it's not a matter of arithmetic addition !). So Maybe `Prepend[{0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1},0.3]` which gives :  {0.3, 0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1} ?

Comment: no-op: an instruction which does nothing

Comment: I think I have understood the enigm of what you wanted to do with `List[0.3, Flatten[Table[i, {i, 10}]]]`. It is `Flatten[List[0.3,Table[i, {i, 10}]]]`, which gives {0.3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general approach which will let you insert a new element at any index is to use the function `Insert`. In case the index would be 1.

```
v = {0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1};
Insert[v, .3, 1]
```

> ```
> {0.3, 0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1}
> ```

A more limited approach, which only works when the element is to be inserted at the beginning of the list, is to use `Prepend`.

```
 Prepend[v, .3]
```

Both of these approaches preserve `v` unchanged, the modified lists returned are new lists. Should you want to destructively modify `v`, you can write

```
 PrependTo[v, .3]
```